# How to create a page with a specific form display?

Tags: forms

And how do form displays work?

I have a content type (*Sketch*) with an image. As an authenticated user, I can create a node of that type from /node/add/sketch, but that uses the default form.

How do I override the form display to use a new form display?

Additionally, how do I put this form on a separate path (for example /sketches/new)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To Enable new form display mode for content type follow these steps:**

A. Go to specific content type(sketch) > click on "manage form display"

B. You will find "Custom display settings" at the end of page click on it

c. then newly added display form displaying here, checked it & form mode 'll enable.

**Additionally, how do I put this form on a separate path: /sketches/new**

**There are two approaches to achieve this:**

**A. Create custom page(controller) with this route /sketches/new**

```
 Get node form object & return it from controller

 **Snippet code:**

 $values = array('type' => 'sketch');

 $node = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
    ->getStorage('node')
    ->create($values);

 $form = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
    ->getFormObject('node', 'sketch_multicolor')
    ->setEntity($node);
  $form =  \Drupal::formBuilder()->getForm($form);
```

Here **'sketch_multicolor'** **machine name of newly added form mode.**

**Additional Info:** if you are using this approach & custom form mode then you need to use below code in .module file: (otherwise you 'll face mentioned error)

```
function module_name_entity_type_build(array &$entity_types) {
  $entity_types['node']->setFormClass('sketch_multicolor', 'Drupal\node\NodeForm');
}
```

Drupal\Component\Plugin\Exception\InvalidPluginDefinitionException: The "node" entity type did not
specify a "sketch_multicolor" form class. in Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeManager->getFormObject() (line 207 of
/var/www/html/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/EntityTypeManager.php).

**B Alter route path : By use of RouteSubscriber:**
In this basically you alter the path from '/node/add/sketch' to this '/sketches/new'

[Click on this reference link to use Routesubscriber approach](https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/routing-system/altering-existing-routes-and-adding-new-routes-based-on-dynamic-ones)

```
 Here you can check **'alterRoutes()'** to update the path.
```